# data-bind in the .js file

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am writing in .js file and trying to loop through each element and add this "self.renderButtons". when i click on delete it should call the remove function. It is not doing that, can anyone help?

```
     self.renderButtons = function (id) {
    return ('<a href="' + '/Product/' + id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-margin-right"><span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span> Details</a>'
    + '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-bind="click: removeItem"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>');
} 
self.removeItem = function (item) {
    $(document).trigger('loader-show');
    self.service.delete(item.Id, self.handleDelete, self.handleError);
};
```

Comment: Which part of your code does not work? Is there any error visible in browser's console?

Comment: when i click delete button, its not going to the removeItem function. There is no error in the console. f_martinez

Comment: Either buttons are being added after all bindings already applied (so `click` bindings are not processed at all), or you should specify the correct context for `removeItem` (e.g. `$root.removeItem`). Please consider to expand your question by adding more details about your viemodel and how the `renderButtons` method is used.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the DOM is Knockout's job. If you want to have a button that corresponds to each element of an array, that is a job for the [`foreach` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html). You manipulate the observableArray, and Knockout will take care of making the DOM reflect that state.